# Verilog assigning multiple reg's or wire's to the same value

Tags: verilog

How can I assign multiple reg's to the same value with more condensed code? This is the code that I want to improve:

```
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
d = 0;
e = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use left-hand concats

The following example shows how to do it.

```
reg a,b,c,d,e;
initial begin
    {a,b,c,d,e} = 5'b0;
end
```

there is no other more 'condenced' way, unless you use an array.

```
reg [4:0] var;
...
var = 5'b0;
```

or for  multi-dimensional unpacked arrays you can use loops

```
reg [1:0] var [4:0];

...
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) var[i] = 0;
```

Comment: Would using loops have a cost overhead, or are the loops run during synthesis?

Comment: synthesis is supposed to unroll the loops an convert it into a 5-wire thing, same as in all other cases.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Hi, I know that I am kind of late, but is it possible to add logical operators to the assignment?
e.g. {a, ~b, ~c,d,e} = 5'b01010; -> 5'b00110==={a,b,c,d,e};

Comment: nope, you cannot use it on left-hand-side, but you can invert your data on rhs:`{a, b, c,d,e} = 5'b00110`. The second expression is correct, though `===` is not synthesizable in general.

Answer (score 2):

If all the variables have the same bit-width, and therefore the *values* you want assigned to those variables have the same bit-width, you can do a replication concatenation:

```
{a,b,c,d,e} = {5{value}};
```